# Insertion fails when invoked in \chapter

Tags: macros, programming

Here is the simplified version of my project. I have a macro named `\CreateMacro` which takes 2 inputs, i.e., the macro name to create and its body. For example, invoking `\CreateMacro{Newton}{$F=ma$.}` will create a new macro `\Newton` with body `$F=ma$`. Behind the scene, there is an auxiliary macro `\Newtonprivate` created. The purpose of `\Newtonprivate` is to format the body with different style, in this example, making the body red.

Everytime the `\Newton` is invoked, `\Newtonprivate` must be pushed into an array-like list. `\Render` then prints `\Newtonprivate` as many as the number of times `\Newtonprivate` has been pushed.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\CreateMacro[2]{%
    \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname#1private\endcsname{\global\@namedef{#1private}{\textcolor{red}{#2}}}% auxiliary private macro
    \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname#1\endcsname{\global\@namedef{#1}{#2\expandafter\addjword{\csname #1private\endcsname}}}%
}




\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Array for words

\newcounter{jwordcount}%
\newcommand\setjword[2]{\csdef{jword#1}{#2}}%
\newcommand\addjword[1]{\stepcounter{jwordcount}\setjword{\thejwordcount}{#1}}%
\newcommand\getjword[1]{\csuse{jword#1}}%

%%% Basic Loop
%Taken from the aloop pof David Salomon's The Advanced TeXbook pg 191
%Use:
%\newcount\temp
%\loop\temp=1 step 1 until 10 do {something} \endloop\temp
\def\loop#1=#2 {%
    \long\def\next step ##1 until ##2 do ##3 \endloop#1{%
        ##3%
    \advance#1 by ##1
    \ifnum#1>##2\relax\else\next step ##1 until ##2 do ##3 \endloop#1 \fi%
    }%end of \next
    #1=#2 \next}%end of \loop

%Return the table containing the current words, reset the counter
\newcommand\render{%
        \newcount\temp\loop\temp=1 step 1 until {\thejwordcount} do {\expandafter\getjword{\@arabic\temp}\ifnum\temp<\thejwordcount\else\fi} \endloop\temp%
        \setcounter{jwordcount}{0}%reset for the next group of words
}


\makeatother


\parindent=0pt


\begin{document}
\CreateMacro{Newton}{$F=ma$.}


\chapter{\protect\Newton}
\render

\Newton\\
\render

\Newton\\
\render

\end{document}
```

## Problems

When I invoke `Newton` inside `\chapter`, the list seems to be still empty. It should not be like this. How to fix this issue?

Comment: `\csuse` and `\csdef` need `etoolbox`, don't they? And are you open to LaTeX3 syntax?

Comment: Your `\expandafter` tries expanding `{` (in both places you're using it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of a chapter is typeset in a group and your list is not updated globally. Use `\csgdef`.

Some other quirks.

1. `\expandafter\addjword{\csname #1private\endcsname}` tries expanding `{` and is completely useless. Either remove `\expandafter` or do

   ```
   \expandafter\addjword\expandafter{\csname #1private\endcsname}
   ```
2. Similarly for `\expandafter\getjword{\@arabic\temp}` that should be

   ```
   \expandafter\getjword\expandafter{\the\temp}
   ```

   (`\the` is more efficient than `\@arabic`).
3. `\newcount\temp` should be outside the definition of `\render` or you waste a counter at each call.
4. The loop you're doing is very cumbersome.

Here's a version in `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\CreateMacro}{mm}
 {
  \cs_new_protected:cpn { #1 }
   {
    #2
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_eirian_push_seq { \eirian_format:n { #2 } }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\render}{ }
 {
  \seq_use:Nn \g_eirian_push_seq {}
  \seq_gclear:N \g_eirian_push_seq
 }

\seq_new:N \g_eirian_push_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \eirian_format:n
 {
  \textcolor{red}{#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\parindent=0pt


\begin{document}
\CreateMacro{Newton}{$F=ma$.}

\chapter{\Newton}
\render

\Newton\Newton\\
\render

\Newton\\
\render

\end{document}
```

Since `\Newton` is “protected”, you don't need `\protect` in front of it.

[image]

A “traditional” version, less flexible.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\CreateMacro}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newrobustcmd\csname #1\endcsname{%
    #2\gappto\pushed{\format{#2}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\format}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\render}{\pushed\gdef\pushed{}}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
\CreateMacro{Newton}{$F=ma$.}

\chapter{\Newton}
\render

\Newton\Newton\\
\render

\Newton\\
\render

\end{document}
```

A version where you can push several things, and render them independently (of course, `\render` needs to have an argument).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\CreateMacro}{mm}
 {
  \seq_new:c { g_eirian_push_#1_seq }
  \cs_new_protected:cpn { #1 }
   {
    #2
    \seq_gput_right:cn { g_eirian_push_#1_seq } { \eirian_format:n { #2 } }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\render}{m}
 {
  \seq_use:cn { g_eirian_push_#1_seq } {~}
  \seq_gclear:c { g_eirian_push_#1_seq }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \eirian_format:n
 {
  \textcolor{red}{#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\parindent=0pt


\begin{document}
\CreateMacro{Newton}{$F=ma$.}
\CreateMacro{Einstein}{$E=mc^2$.}

\chapter{\Newton}
\render{Newton}

\Newton\Einstein\Newton\\
\render{Newton}\render{Einstein}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your `\expandafter` triple in your examples causes that the `{` is expanded by the second `\expandafter`. You did mention this mistake but you did this mistake again.

Comment: @wipet Yes, the triple expandafter is not needed.

Comment: The first example is corrected now only partially. The parameter of the `\adjword` is `\Newtonprivate` control sequence but not the contents of the `\Newtonprivate` macro.

Comment: @wipet That's what the OP wants and it doesn't really matter whether having it or the first level expansion. That's why I deem useless the `\expandafter` in the first instance.

Answer (score 2):

Your `\csdef` in `\setjword` does not survive the group but I `\csgdef` does.

But honestly, I think that the code can be rearranged. I try to improve it later on.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\CreateMacro[2]{%
    \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname#1private\endcsname{\global\@namedef{#1private}{\textcolor{red}{#2}}}% auxiliary private macro
    \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname#1\endcsname{\global\@namedef{#1}{#2\expandafter\addjword{\csname #1private\endcsname}}}%
}




\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Array for words

\newcounter{jwordcount}%
\newcommand\setjword[2]{\csgdef{jword#1}{#2}}%
\newcommand\addjword[1]{\stepcounter{jwordcount}\setjword{\thejwordcount}{#1}}%
\newcommand\getjword[1]{\csuse{jword#1}}%

%%% Basic Loop
%Taken from the aloop pof David Salomon's The Advanced TeXbook pg 191
%Use:
%\newcount\temp
%\loop\temp=1 step 1 until 10 do {something} \endloop\temp
\def\loop#1=#2 {%
    \long\def\next step ##1 until ##2 do ##3 \endloop#1{%
        ##3%
    \advance#1 by ##1
    \ifnum#1>##2\relax\else\next step ##1 until ##2 do ##3 \endloop#1 \fi%
    }%end of \next
    #1=#2 \next}%end of \loop

%Return the table containing the current words, reset the counter
\newcommand\render{%
        \newcount\temp\loop\temp=1 step 1 until {\thejwordcount} do {\expandafter\getjword{\@arabic\temp}\ifnum\temp<\thejwordcount\else\fi} \endloop\temp%
        \setcounter{jwordcount}{0}%reset for the next group of words
}


\makeatother


\parindent=0pt


\begin{document}
\CreateMacro{Newton}{$F=ma$.}


\chapter{\protect\Newton}
Render here: \render


Again: \Newton\\
\render

\Newton\\
\render

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that something is overcomplicated here. In plain TeX, it is possible to solve your task by:

```
\input opmac

\def\renderlist{}
\def\createmacro#1#2{\addprotect#1%
   \def#1{#2\global\addto\renderlist{\formatmacro{#2}}}}
\def\render{\renderlist\gdef\renderlist{}}
\def\formatmacro#1{{\localcolor\Red#1}}

\createmacro\Newton{$F=ma$.}

\chap \Newton

\render

\Newton:
\render

\Newton, \Newton:
\render

\end
```

If your environment is LaTeX then use package `xcolor` and try

```
\def\renderlist{}
\def\createmacro#1#2{%
   \protected\def#1{#2%
      \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\renderlist\expandafter
         {\renderlist\formatmacro{#2}}}}
\def\render{\renderlist\gdef\renderlist{}}
\def\formatmacro#1{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\createmacro\Newton{$F=ma$.}
...
```

Comment: Which are, essentially, repetitions of my code. Can you tell where they differ? Perhaps in not using `\gappto`? Well, that's just syntactic sugar.

Comment: We nedn't to create control sequence using `\csname...\endcsname` but we can write directly `\createmacro\Newton`. This is more natural. And I used similar `\gobal\addto` in my plain TeX code.